# Sorting URLS before I check for duplicates in VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, filter

I'm trying to run a few filters using VBA, where I then have the data output to an "analysis" sheet.

Everything works as it should so far - but I'm now trying to eliminate URL duplicates.

`If unique_1 <> Sheets(1).Cells(x, 11) Then`

The code snippet above will eliminate the duplicates, but only if I have already sorted by URLS (which is not something I can do with the data upfront)

I'm hoping I can sort using VBA, but haven't been able to so far and my eyes are killing me. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
If Sheets(1).Cells(x, 12) = "X URL" Then
        If Sheets(1).Cells(x, 9) > 4 And Sheets(1).Cells(x, 9) < 10 Then               
            '//NEED TO SORT URLS HERE FIRST - BEFORE I CAN FIND DUPES//                
            If unique_1 <> Sheets(1).Cells(x, 11) Then
                O_2 = O_2 + 1
            End If
               unique_1 = Sheets(1).Cells(x, 11)
        End If
End If
```

Comment: I usually rely on recording a macro when creating a sort in my code - there are quite a few arguments; so I record the sorting and then play around with the code generated. (always feels a bit dirty recording macros but no point trying to remember everything)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Range.Sort` on whatever range you are trying [to sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238871%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

As a side note, nothing in the code you listed seems to remove duplicates. At most, it counts how many there are.

Comment: "If unique_1 <> Sheets(1).Cells(x, 11) Then" is the section that will specificlly count how many non-dupes there are (but only if they're sorted first) - I didn't mean remove/delete - but eliminate them from the total count.  Range.Sort - I tried using, but couldn't get the formatting correctly as it kept throwing errors based on all the samples I could find..

Comment: Go ahead and do what you want your code to do [while recording a macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/record-and-use-excel-macros-HA001054837.aspx). You should be able to easily use the generated code for what you want.

Comment: @EpicVision: You don't need to sort to remove duplicates. Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: Think this could be done with autofilter to remove duplicates

Comment: That would be great - I just had the code that would remove the duplicates but only if it was sorted first. Soo I'm open to other suggestions..  Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misreading the question why not use an auto filter for unique entries?
This will output a list in a column you specify so you can see what's happened.

```
    Range("URL Range").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range( _
        "Output Range"), Unique:=True
```